# Split String with Custom conditions and delimeters

Tags: c#, .net, string, linq, split

What's the best way to split these string to a `List<customObject>`?

```
[
    [
        "a",
        "123",
        "456"
    ],
    [
        "b",
        "456",
        "789"
    ]
]
```

Say, I want to get the List of SampleObject with definition:

```
class SampleObject
{
    public string Letter { get; set; }
    public string FirstNumber { get; set; }
    public string SecondNumber{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It looks like JSON. Maybe you should use JSON parser?

Comment: Yeah. it's a `JSON` without data keynames. @MarcinJuraszek

Comment: If you can't use a JSON parser, a regex would be better than Split.

Comment: @lexeRoy Try deserializing it to `string[][]` array, and then transform that array into your class instances.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek tried it already, it prompts `Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.String[][]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.`. I already posted a question about parsing JSON with keynames yesterday, but am not lucky to receive any insights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use Json.Net's [Jarray.Parse](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray_Parse.htm) method for this. This is the example from their web help:

```
string json = @"[
  'Small',
  'Medium',
  'Large'
]";

JArray a = JArray.Parse(json);
```

You can create instances of your objects and then load from each element in the array.

Here is a working example that uses your sample string and class:

```
JArray aAllValues = JArray.Parse(json);
var SampleObjectCollection = new List<SampleObject>();

foreach (JArray aValues in aAllValues)
{
    var oSampleObject = new SampleObject();
    int index = 0;

    foreach (var oProperty in aValues.Children())
    {
        switch (index)
        {
            case 0:
                oSampleObject.Letter = oProperty.Value<String>();
                break;
            case 1:
                oSampleObject.FirstNumber = oProperty.Value<String>();
                break;
            case 2:
                oSampleObject.SecondNumber = oProperty.Value<String>();
                break;
        }

        index++;
    }

    SampleObjectCollection.Add(oSampleObject);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can deserialize it using Json.Net into a dynamic object and then fill your custom objects

```
dynamic items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);
var list = new List<SampleObject>();

foreach (var item in items)
{ 
    var sampleObject = new SampleObject
                           {
                               Letter = item[0].ToString(),
                               FirstNumber = item[1].ToString(),
                               SecondNumber = item[2].ToString()
                           }
    list.Add(sampleObject);        
}
```

Comment: Can't deserialize this since key names were not included in the array context.

Comment: I was able to make it work in a test I did with your test data

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to use your dynamic. Will +1 this since it's working too. Thanks man!